# C# Linq for files user has read access to

Tags: c#, linq, file-permissions, acl

How would I use Linq on `list.Items = directoryInfo.GetFiles("\\server\share\folder\");` to include only the files the user has read access to?

...
So far only suggestions are using try/catches, or APIs that are obsolete in .NET 4.0? I'd prefer something to read the ACL's and see if the specific user or a group the user is a member of has been granted read access. I'm trying to do this for simplified management of granting reports to users on a website that won't be high traffic, so the logic that "who knows if you can actually read it when you try to open the file" doesn't pertain to this case. I sense that Microsoft should really make this task easier.

Answer (score 1):

just try this out .should work .haven't tested though

```
  var fw = from f in new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\").GetFiles()
                where SecurityManager.IsGranted(new FileIOPermission
 (FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, f.FullName))
                select f;
```

**EDIT** if it is just read only files then try this

```
var fe = from f in new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\ashley\\Downloads\\").GetFiles()
                where f.IsReadOnly==true
                select f
```

Comment: You might be able to [use the solution from this question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978612/how-to-check-if-a-windows-file-is-readable-writable).

Comment: yeah ..but stating some logic inside catch doesn't sound very elegent.Imagine you have thousands of files and waiting for exception to occure to get its state is pretty expensive operation..

Comment: @Ashley: Those try/catch I'm pretty sure are special cases (a drive doesn't exist, or you are completely locked out of a folder).  You can call that function from within a Linq query, so your higher level code can still be pretty.  It already encapsulates the true/false, so you'd just need to plug it into a `where` clause.  I don't know if there is a better option without using p/Invoke (e.g. a `Try` variant).  Also I think enumerating the files on the filesystem might be a bottleneck already.  I speculate the exception will be negligible at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You run the risk of a race condition if you check for read permission prior to opening the file.

If you're attempting to read all of the files you have access to in a folder, better to just try opening each one and catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

See:

- [how can you easily check if access is denied for a file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net)
- [How do you check for permissions to write to a directory or file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130617/how-do-you-check-for-permissions-to-write-to-a-directory-or-file)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I haven't tested it, but in theory it should work

First, define a predicate to determine read access

```
bool CanRead(FileInfo file)
{
  try {
    file.GetAccessControl();
    //Read and write access;
    return true;
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
  {
    if (uae.Message.Contains("read-only"))
    {
      //read-only access
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

Then, it should be a simple case of using a where clause in a linq query

```
from file in directoryInfo.GetFiles("\\server\share\folder\") 
  where HaveAccess(f) == true
    select f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working, but will return false if the file is in use

```
void Main()
{
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
    var currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles(".").Where(f => CanRead(currentUser, f.FullName));
}

private bool CanRead(WindowsIdentity user, string filePath)
{
    if(!File.Exists(filePath))
        return false;

    try
    {
        var fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(filePath, AccessControlSections.Access); 
        foreach(FileSystemAccessRule fsRule in fileSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)))
        {
            foreach(var usrGroup in user.Groups)
            {
                if(fsRule.IdentityReference.Value == usrGroup.Value)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
        //File is in use
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this work for groups within groups?  How about explicit deny permissions?